# Laravel new domain doesn't work

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, nginx, laravel-5.3

I have a project working on a subdamin that I changed already and created a new alias to the new one.

In my .env file and configuration files I have set the new domain and reset the server. But I'm getting a 301 redirect to the old domain.

What I have to do? Is this a Laravel thing? I changed the new url on this files:

.env
cache/config.php
config/app.php

Maybe is something with nginx configuration?

My version is Laravel 5.3

Comment: tried `composer dump-autoload`, `php artisan view:clear`, `php artisan cache:clear`? do you use forge or similar?

Comment: @M.Elwan Yes I tried the 3 options , I don't use Forge though

Answer (score 0):

What about your .htaccess file. Have you checked if all of the urls in there are pointing to your sub domain?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using homestead, go in to your homestead `vagrant ssh` inside the homestead folder.

navigate to `/etc/nginx/sites-available`

vi/nano `/etc/nginx/sites-available/{sitename}`

add `server_name *.{yourdomain};
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';`

run `sudo service nginx restart`

and don't forget to add `subdomain.domain.dev`   to your `/etc/hosts` file.

**NOTE:** every time you run provision, you'll have to redo this.